# How to block all traffic except for browsing?

Tags: internet, iptables, traffic

Sorry for the paranoid question but is it possible to block all connections except for Firefox and updates?
And if so does someone got a terminal code for it?

Comment: I would at least add dns traffic to your allow list else there is not much to surf :-)

Comment: Ok sorry im kind of new to all of this so, but if you know a way to achieve this than can you please tell me ??

Comment: I find the question too big, making a complete answer on this and test it would take me too long. I can give a possible solution on how you would be able to program a script allowing you to do this, but I am not gonna make it for you.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway for helping me i now got Gufu installed and it let me make rules for programs but i cant find firefox in it but is this a way to achieve this ?

Comment: If the actual question is how to close all traffic except for browsing, please update your question accordingly else the question and answer do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Install the software called Uncomplicated Firewall. Open it and select "block all traffic". Then create rules for TCP/UDP to ALLOW OUTGOING dns and http (DESTINATION port 53, port 80 and port 443).

Comment: That was not the question, it allows all traffic with port 80, not just firefox.

Comment: I bet he meant that he just wants to allow web traffic through.

Comment: Yes, thats correct and i now got gufw installed and reject in and outgoing traffic so i now only have to make some rules for Firefox updates doesn't have to because i can simply set the firewall to allow traffic when i want to install updates.
So if someone go the port of Firefox than i can make a rule in Gufu :)

Comment: Yup, pretty much. Watch out for your firewall logs though and make sure that important stuff does not get denied access, like security updates that may use different ports.

Comment: Ok but will it only allow firefox or will it also allow other applications i now got the following rule and it seems to work on firefox and block software center :  80,443/TCP Allow out Anywhere out

Comment: I would suggest a Shorewall firewall but that requires a bit more configuring